# Sqlite data file on Linux and OS X incompatible?

Tags: linux, macos, sqlite

I create a table and fill it by executing the following on an ARM Linux machine

```
~ # sqlite3 /mnt/mmc/test.db
SQLite version 3.6.12
sqlite> create table a (d);
sqlite> insert into a values (1.5);
sqlite> select * from a;
1.5
```

I then transfer the file to my Mac and execute the following

```
themac:~ me$ sqlite3 test.db 
SQLite version 3.6.12
sqlite> select * from a;
5.30239915051991e-315
```

Whaaat? I thought the data file was platform independent.

Comment: By any chance is the Mac an older PPC model? (ie. big endian)

Comment: For what it's worth I just tested the exact same sequence of instructions going from an x86 linux machine to an x86 OS X machine and selecting out the value returns 1.5.

Comment: It's an Intel Mac Book Pro of the newer kind (2-3 years old).

Comment: Have you tried defining the column with a datatype?  e.g. create table a (d float) ? Can you test with integer values, i.e. (d integer) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no particular knowledge of SQLite, but this is indicative of a problem where two 32-bit words of a 64-bit IEEE 754 format `double` are swapped over, as you can see in this example (which was run using `gcc` on an x86 machine):

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    union {
        double d;
        unsigned long long ull;
    } u;

    u.d = 1.5;
    printf("%016llx\n", u.ull);

    u.d = 5.30239915051991e-315;
    printf("%016llx\n", u.ull);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test test.c
$ ./test
3ff8000000000000
000000003ff80000
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The file format is platform independent, at least according to http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html

> A database in SQLite is a single disk
>   file. Furthermore, the file format is
>   cross-platform. A database that is
>   created on one machine can be copied
>   and used on a different machine with a
>   different architecture. SQLite
>   databases are portable across 32-bit
>   and 64-bit machines and between
>   big-endian and little-endian
>   architectures.

Is it possible that the file was corrupted during transfer? Can you run `md5sum` in both environments and confirm the files are identical?

Comment: On ze Linux ("md5sum") and Mac ("md5"), respectively: b7b8210c3a8bcc3e59359feea6301a68 and b7b8210c3a8bcc3e59359feea6301a68. They are the same.

Comment: It looks to me like a bug in sqlite. Their bug-reporting page is here: http://www.sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=Bug+Reports

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.