# Are sqlite3 databases are platform independent?

Tags: sqlite

I have situation where sqlite3 database created in windows and I want them to process it in Ubuntu machine. When I try to open them in Ubuntu with:

```
sqlite3 dbname
```

inside the console, for all comments I am getting error message as:

```
Error: malformed database schema (updateTimeStampActions) - no such table: main.actions
```

How can I process the database in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Sqlite website, the db file is platform independent:

" A database in SQLite is a single disk file. Furthermore, the file format is cross-platform. A database that is created on one machine can be copied and used on a different machine with a different architecture. SQLite databases are portable across 32-bit and 64-bit machines and between big-endian and little-endian architectures"

Please follow the link: http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html

You can refer to this thread for further explanation: [Sqlite data file on Linux and OS X incompatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084037/sqlite-data-file-on-linux-and-os-x-incompatible)

Comment: thanks for the info. But is there any possibility to get the data from the file?

Comment: The table name 'main.actions' suggests that on Windows you have a linked database called 'main' with the table 'actions'.  So you would probably need to copy that database to the Ubuntu system.  Might be an idea to check the schema on the Windows system for any other gotchas.